# How to backup topic configuration for Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

So I'm migrating an old instance (0.9.0... yeah I know, upgrade is phase 2) of Kafka, and I want to transfer the topic config.  I'm kind of thinking of a "schema dump", I know that's not the term but just a metadata and no data.

So, the ideal backup would have topic list, number of partitions, number of replications, retention time, etc... something I'm missing.

Comment: Topic configuration is in Zookeeper, so sure, you could backup the znode, but an in place upgrade should preserve (and migrate) that data anyway.

Comment: @cricket_007 I must have been unclear. This is not an in place upgrade. This is “move from one machine to another”. I don’t like binary backups - what tool can I dump a complete config with?  Thanks

Comment: There's no tool built into Kafka... Maybe this? https://github.com/ksprojects/zkcopy

Comment: @cricket_007 close. I’d like to dump to a file so I can do backups. I can start here. Thank you